# Drop down list items count is working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list, which has first item hard coded and other are bind by sql data source. Now on C# code I want this drop down list's items count which I'm getting 1 always (the first hard coded list item). while this drop down list is properly showing all list item on browser. I'm not able to understand the exact problem.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroup" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsGroupListByUserId"
     Width="100px" DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupID" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">N/A</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsGroupListByUserId" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EMSsql %>" SelectCommand="GetGroup_ByEventID" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="EventID" SessionField="EventID" Type="Int64" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And this is how i'm trying to fetch items count-

```
int ItemsCount = ddlGroup.Items.Count;
```

Comment: Where (and when) do you call your second line?

Comment: Do you call databind before getting the count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your databind in a !Page.IsPostBack.

Everything gets refreshed everytime the page is postback, which is why your count is 1 because it is the only list item client side.  Anything populated server side will need to be in a not post back.

```
If (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
ddlGroup.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: @ShilpaSoni No problem, but if this answer helped you out, check it as the correct answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are not using [Page.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property into `page_Load`.

Use `IsPostBack` into Page_load like

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         // Bind your dropdown.
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.